# How to debug LinqPad query in Visual Studio Debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, linqpad

I can attach the debugger and get it to break - but it has trouble finding the .cs file, I think LinqPad deletes it as part of its build.. 8-(

Comment: Note that after this question was asked, Linqpad introduced a new, premium edition of Linqpad which includes its own debugger.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you call

```
Debugger.Launch();
Debugger.Break();
```

to initiate the breakpoint within your LINQPad script, LINQPad will guess that you want to use VS to debug your script and won't delete the .cs file.

Comment: I just had another go with a C# Program like this 'code'void Main()
{
 Debugger.Launch();
 int i = 0;
 Debugger.Break();
 i.Dump();
}'code'  VS launches fails to find the code. BUT then running again from LP, VS then find the the .cs file....

Comment: I was having trouble with this, then realized I was trying to attach a VS 2008 debugger to LINQPad.exe; it *has* to be a version of VS that supports .NET 4+ (such as VS 2012).

Answer (score 25):

- Start LINQPad
- In VS, open Debug -> Attach to Process...
- Choose LINQPad.exe
- Set breakpoint in your code called by LINQPad C# code, or write Debugger.Break() in your LINQPad script where you want the debugger to halt.
- Execute the script from LINQPad and watch the magic.

Comment: You should check Debugger.IsAttached property before calling Debugger.Break().

Answer (score 3):

If your LINQPad code is calling a method in some referenced C# assembly and you want to debug that assembly in Visual Studio 2015, this worked for me:

1. Build your solution.
2. Optionally, run your LINQPad script, let it crash, etc. In the lower right LINQPad status bar, notice the PID in light blue coloring.
3. In VS, CTRL + ALT + P to attach to process. Attach to the LINQPad UserQuery process with the PID you saw.
4. Place a breakpoint here in VS.
5. Run the linqpad query and pop over to VS. You should hit your breakpoint!